# How do I find out what's slowing down in my app?

Tags: objective-c, ios, performance

I have put `NSLog` points throughout the launch stuff of my app, including delegate methods. The last one I can find that gets hit, gets hit about 2 seconds before `viewDidAppear`. How can I find out where my app is slowing down?

Comment: Have you tried using Instruments?

Comment: Nope. I've only ever used that for leaks before. How do i use it to find this out?

Comment: As James suggested TimeProfiler could be a valid solution. If you provide some code it could be possible to understand  what is going on. Maybe you perform some calculations that could be executed in background..

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Time Profiler tool on Instruments for determining how long each call takes.

Answer (score 1):

In xcode you can use Instruments tools. It's really useful when looking for memoryleaks, performance issues etc.

Trigger the problem while using the tools.

See the Apple link for getting started with Apple Developer tools.
[Apple Developer Tools](http://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=xcode%20developer%20instruments%20tools&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CC0QFjAB&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/developertools/conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/index.html&ei=olpGT4y7NMHh4QSmh6nVDg&usg=AFQjCNEo_avL4tsRgcVWOHQDMet_kZMuOQ&sig2=OCS5tXi5hFN3mb3TQshrxw&cad=rja)

Best,

Answer (score 0):

In your question, you note that you're using NSLog statements, which can be useful, but at the same time setting breakpoints can be even easier and provide more insight to your problems. Try adding a breakpoint in the tray on the left side of your code. You can also set conditional breakpoints to analyze the code that is being stopped on.

Combining the use of breakpoints with **Instruments** can greatly help you understand your apps performance and possible problems. You can find the Instruments application in Xcode 4 under the Xcode menu. Click Xcode -> Developer Tools -> Instruments. You can also *Profile* your app with instruments by clicking and holding on the *Run* button and then selecting *Profile*:  [image: Profile App]

You should then see a screen like this:  [image: Instruments]
Select **Time Profiler** to determine how long each call takes. Then click **Profile**